# Passing two arguments

Tags: c, pointers, prototype, pass-by-reference

I want to pass two arguments into *void Dividing* from *void Assign_numbers* and *void Maximum*. I have only learnt to pass one argument at a time. Can you please tell me what I have to do print out the following variables inside *void Dividing*. If it's possible, I don't want the format of my code to change drastically. Can you also show me an example, since I am a visual learner. Thanks

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define Max 6

struct Numbers
{
    double a,b,c,d,e,f;
};

void Maximum(double *ptr);
void Dividing(double Maximum, double *ptr);

void Assign_numbers()
{
    struct Numbers number;

    number.a=45.78;
    number.b=81.45;
    number.c=56.69;
    number.d=34.58;
    number.e=23.57;
    number.f=78.35;

    Maximum((double*) &number);
    Dividing((double*) &number);
}

void Maximum(double *ptr)
{
    int i=0;
    double Maximum = ptr[0];

    for(i;i<Max;i++)
    {
        if(ptr[i]> Maximum)
        {
            Maximum = ptr[i];
        }
    }
    Dividing(Maximum);
}

void Dividing(double Maximum, double *ptr)
{
    printf("%.2f", Maximum);
    printf("%.2f",ptr[3]);
}

int main()
{
    Assign_numbers();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You see those `printf` calls you make? You manage to make them with two arguments.

Comment: Oh, and like I said before that you can't reliably use a structure as an array. While it might work in this particular case on your operating system with your compiler and standard library, ***don't do it!*** It's not portable, it will lead to weird behavior when you least expect it, and it makes the code unmaintainable. If I was your professor and you gave me code like that I would fail you immediately.

Comment: Not only is @JoachimPileborg correct that this code isn't portable (it relies on undefined behavior) it is ridiculously inflexible. What possible motivation can anyone have to write a function which can calculate the max of 6 numbers when the same (or even less) amount of work can give you a function which can calculate the max of an arbitrary array of numbers?

Comment: Joachim Pileborg or John Coleman - I'm new to C, so I'm just experimenting. Can you please explain to me why its not portable ? And why is it better to initialize the array in the function itself ? I'm trying to find documents about it and my book doesn't really explain in detail. Thanks.

Comment: You are assuming that you know the memory layout of a struct -- but the C standard doesn't specify it. In particular, there is sometimes *padding* between struct elements which is inserted so as to better align the fields with the processor's word-size. Also -- in learning C, it is probably a better strategy to read more and experiment less, at least at first. C isn't one of those languages that you can pick up by trial and error.

Comment: So in other words since there is no specific memory allocated to struct, I'm not really passing the value in my functions in array form.

Comment: And the only reason why my code worked was because my compiler inserted a padding in between my struct values. I'm just making sure if I understand it. thanks

Comment: Your code worked because your compiler *didn't* insert padding between struct elements so that pointer arithmetic was able to go from one struct element to the next. If there has padding and `p` is a double pointer pointing to the first element of the struct, then `p+1` would point to padding (with `(p+1)*` dereferencing to some weird combination of padding and part of the next struct element).

Comment: One more question - I iterated my struct using (double*) in my "void Assign_numbers", so I assumed that got rid of the padding. Does iterating cancel the padding of the struct? I'm just curious. Sorry for being so persistent .

Comment: This is my last answer -- your code doesn't *cancel* any padding, your code simply *hopes* that it isn't there, and programming shouldn't be based on hope. As a general rule of thumb -- don't used casting unless you really understand what you are doing. Since casting subverts type-checking it is somewhat dangerous and should be used sparingly.

Comment: As all the comments says so far. You need to parse two parameters to the function when the function is specified to have two parameters. And then there is the whole pointer thing. I have edited my bottom answer for the final time. Have a look at the examples. It should all be working code. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Thanks guys. Especially to John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use array instead of struct - shwon here with reference example

Like Joachim Pileborg said. Don't use a struct as an array. In your case use a multidimensional array.

```
double[10][6] numbers;
```

You can easily iterate through such an array like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   /* an array with 2 rows and 6 columns*/
   double numbers[2][6] = { 
       {45.78, 81.45, 56.69, 34.58, 23.57, 78.35},
       {1,2,3,4,5, 6}
   };

   int i, j;
   /* output each array element's value */
   for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
      for ( j = 0; j < 6; j++ ) {
         printf("numbers[%d][%d] = %f\n", i,j, numbers[i][j] );
      }
   }
   /* Output by reference */
   for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
       for(j=0; j < 6; j++ ){
           printf("numbers[%d][%d] = %f\n", i, j,*(*(numbers + i) + j));
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

### Why the current code fails

Now onto explaining how your code (does not) work and a little about how pointers work. First off:

```
Dividing(double Maximum, double* ptr);
```

Does not work in the way you think it does. "double Maximum" is a new double variable that works within the scope of Dividing and is not a variable retrieved from the function:

```
 void Maximum(double *ptr);
```

If you already knew this, then you should know or at least have expected how poor the naming of your variables are(keep it lowerCamelCase).

Now lets get onto what you're trying to do. IMHO your code is completely broken unless I am noticeing something. In Assign_numbers() you want to call Dividing() using a pointer reference. In Maximum() you want to call Dividing() again, but this time sending only a value. It doesn't make it better that you have 2 separate different calls that each have one parameter. But the function has to have two parameters. Now in order to iterate through the variables in a struct - again this is not recommended and the bottom code only serves as an example.

```
struct Numbers
{
    double a,b,c,d,e,f;
};

struct Numbers Assign_numbers()
{
    struct Numbers number;
    number.a=45.78;
    number.b=81.45;
    number.c=56.69;
    number.d=34.58;
    number.e=23.57;
    number.f=78.35;

    return number;
}

int main()
{
    struct Numbers number;
    number = Assign_numbers(number);

    double *value = &(number.a); //take address of the first element, since a pointer always counts upwards.
    int i;
    /*This loops through the addresses of the struct starting from the initial address in number.a and moves upwards 5 times and hopefully ends in number.f. Seriously bad way to construct arrays*/
    /*Just try replacing sizeof(number) with sizeof(double). suddenly you get all kinds of weird values because you have ended up outside of the struct*/
    /*Also note that this only works when all the datatypes in the struct have a size of 8 bytes(the size of double) */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(number) / sizeof(double); i++){
        printf("[%d]: %f\n",i, value[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### New working code

With all that said. This is the closest I am going to to be able to make your code work since I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define Max 6

struct Numbers
{
    double a,b,c,d,e,f;
};

void Maximum(double *ptr);
void Dividing(double *ptr);

void Assign_numbers()
{
    struct Numbers number;

    number.a=45.78;
    number.b=81.45;
    number.c=56.69;
    number.d=34.58;
    number.e=23.57;
    number.f=78.35;

    Maximum(&number.a); //You need to parse the very first address of the struct. IN this case 'a'
    Dividing(&number.a);
}

void Maximum(double *ptr)
{
    int i=0;
    double maximum = ptr[0];

    for(i;i<Max;i++)
    {
        if(ptr[i]> maximum)
        {
            maximum = ptr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("maximum: %f", maximum);
}

/*//removed the first parameter since it was not clear what it was for and you only had function calls to this function with one parameter */
void Dividing(double *ptr)
{
    printf("%.2f",ptr[3]);
}

int main()
{
    Assign_numbers();
    return 0;
}
```